# Invalid zip file getting generated from a byte array

Tags: java, io, zip

I am trying to compress set of files and storing it to memory .
Below is the code I am using

```
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream zipBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ZipOutputStream zs = new ZipOutputStream(zipBaos)) {
            Path pp = Paths.get(sourceDirPath);
            Files.walk(pp)
                    .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path) && pp.relativize(path).toString().contains(instituteId)
                            && pp.relativize(path).toString().contains("dumps-" + hostCount))
                    .forEach(LambdaExceptionUtil.rethrowConsumer(path -> {

                        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(pp.relativize(path).toString());
                        try {
                            downloadedfilename.add(zipEntry.getName().substring(
                                    zipEntry.getName().lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1, zipEntry.getName().length()));
                            zs.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                            Files.copy(path, zs);
                            zs.closeEntry();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            LOGGER.error("Exception in Zipping downloaded files {}", e);
                            throw e;

                        }
                    }));
            return zipBaos.toByteArray();
        }

    }
```

Now later when I am trying store this byte array content again in the file system as a form of zip file
`FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(location + File.separator + name), content);`
Zip file is getting created and it is showing proper size as well .
But when I am trying to open the file windows complaining it to be invalid.

Note: **I can open it with 7Zip but not with the windows explorer.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ZipOutputStream  finish() and flush() resolved the issue

```
zs.finish();
zs.flush();
return zipBaos.toByteArray();
```